# Print to remote Comm Port in VB6

Tags: printing, vb6

I have a software that prints out to a thermal printer connected to the comm port, the code below works well.

Open "COM3:" For Output Access Write As #1

```
   Print #1, Space(8) & "FRAKAS LTD"       
   Print #1, Space(7) & "P.O. Box 7678 SHIMONI" 
   ...
   ...
```

Close #1

Now I want to print on the same comm port but from a different computer on the network, is it possible?

Comment: What version of Windows is the computer where the thermal printer is hooked up using?  Is this printer selectable from other applications?

Comment: all the computers are running windows 7 professional. The thermal printer can be seen on the printers and devices as an unknown device,so u cant even print to it like a normal printer from other applications,u must go through the comm port,that printer doesnt have windows 7 drivers.

Comment: Have you tried setting up the printer as "Generic/Text Only" from the Windows 7 print driver selection?  I've had to do this with some older impact receipt printers and it works OK sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the serial port across the network by running software at each end. There is some info on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_port_redirector) about some solutions - I haven't tried any.

We have used ethernet to serial converters from Moxa - these redirect a local COM port to a remote one without any PC at the remote end. One example is [here](http://www.moxa.com/product/NPort_5110.htm)

Answer (score 0):

if the printer is availabe then you can use the following to prepare text to be printed :

```
printer.print "text"
```

to start the actual printing you use the following :

```
printer.enddoc
```